# Views RSS post date removal

Tags: views, 6, feeds, datetime

What is the best way to remove the post date from a views created RSS feed? I have a calendar that I have created a feed for, but it is being sorted by a cck date value, making the post date not necessarily accurate.

Is there an easy way to remove this from within views (D6), or would this need to be a template change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This approach](http://drupal.org/node/174359#comment-1654474) should work. I've tried it in the past and it did exactly what I needed.

Quoted from the above-linked comment:

Put `views-view-row-rss.tpl.php` in your theme directory

and replace `print $item_elements`;

with

```
$item_elements = preg_replace('<pubDate>.*</pubDate>', '', $item_elements);  // removes pubdate
$item_elements = preg_replace('<dc:creator>.*</dc:creator>', '', $item_elements);  // removes author
$item_elements = preg_replace('<category .*</category>', '', $item_elements);  // removes terms         

$item_elements = preg_replace("!^\s+(\D)!m", "\\1", $item_elements);  // removes some blank lines

print $item_elements;
```

Comment: I just tried the patch to views-view-row-rss.tpl.php in Drupal 7 and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this about two years ago, so it is possible that things have improved since.

From memory I think you need to do a template change for this kind of thing in views rss feeds. It was not as flexible as it could be.